# Evaluate the following integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I tried solving the question using substitution, but I always seem to end up with a recursive formula. Any hints about how to do the question?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.$$

Comment: Solve the recurrence.

Comment: [On this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279465/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integral-using-hypergeometric-function), there is a clean answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Set $x=\sin y$ to get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}y\ dy=I_{2n+1}$$

Form [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Examples), $$I_m=\dfrac{m-1}mI_{m-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Set $x=\sin (u)$ and $dx=\cos (u)du$ then $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (u)}=\cos(u)$ and $u=\arcsin(x)$

So

$$\int\sin^{2n+1}(u)du$$

And now use the [reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae)