# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{-\frac{2}{3}}(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Calculate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{-\frac{2}{3}}(x) dx$$
**Attempt**
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x) dx =\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})  \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{2 \Gamma(\frac{m+n+2}{2})}  $$
Can we apply this formula to $m=0 $ and $n=-2/3$ which is a negative rational number? Please provide any other method if the above does not hold.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks for the edit. Please answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Try going back to how you derived the formula- what are the assumptions you made and check whether this substitution violates any.

Comment: @DatBoi Can't we do it any other way? Is this formula valid for n being a negative rational number?

Comment: Yes, we can. The formula is valid for $m,n>-1$, and the arguments of Gamma-functions are positive under these conditions. In your case $n=-\frac{2}{3}$ and $m=0$.

Comment: @Syyatoslav thanks a lot. Please provide me a reference that the formula is valid for $m , n> -1$

Comment: @miracle173 Please reply

Comment: Beta-function https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/beta-function

Comment: @Sara, I don't know how to solve your problem.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks. But I am asking for a reference where the formula $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x) dx =\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})  \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{2 \Gamma(\frac{m+n+2}{2})}  $$ is valid for $m,n> -1$?

Comment: @Svyastoslav I need a written result that the above formula is valid for $m,n>-1$

Comment: $B(a,b)=\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2a-1}(x) \cos^{2b-1}(x) dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$. Beta-function (as this integral) is defined for $a,b>0$ (more generally, for $\Re (\,a,b)\,>0$)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank a lot. But reference? Any website, where this formula is written to be valid for $m,n>-1$?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/beta-function  if $b>0$ $n=2b-1>-1$

Comment: @Svyatoslav But in this link this formula written below is not shown to hold for $m,n>-1$ $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x) dx =\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})  \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{2 \Gamma(\frac{m+n+2}{2})}  $$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Please write it as an answer and I will haplily give it a check mark.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Please write it as an answer.

Comment: Here is one answer, simply do the cofunction identity for sin:[power integral of sin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279465/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integral-using-hypergeometric-function)

Comment: I think @Svyatoslav already answered this when commenting the derivation of this form of the beta function. Also just googling it will give you several sources, even wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative is to use the binomial expansion theorem,
the duplication formula of the $\Gamma$-function and known
formulas for the hypergeometric series:
$$
I\equiv \int \frac{1}{\cos^{2/3}(x)} dx
=
\int \frac{1}{(1-\sin^2 x)^{1/3}} dx
=
\sum_{l\ge 0} \binom{-1/3}{l}\int (-\sin^2 x)^l dx
$$
$$
=
\sum_{l\ge 0} (-)^l \frac{(-1/3)(-4/3)(-7/3)\cdots (-1/3-l+1)}{l!}\int \sin^{2l} x dx
$$
$$
=
\sum_{l\ge 0} \frac{(1/3)(4/3)(7/3)\cdots (1/3+l-1)}{l!}\int \sin^{2l} x dx
$$
$$
=
\sum_{l\ge 0}  \frac{(1/3)_l}{l!}\int \sin^{2l} x dx
$$
where $(a)_n=\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$ is Pochhammer's symbol.
In general
$$
\int \sin^{2n}x dx = \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}x+\frac{(-)^n}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-)\binom{2n}{k}\frac{\sin(2n-2k)x}{2n-2k},
$$
so
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2m}x dx =\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(2m)!}{(2^m m!)^2}
.
$$
$$
I=
\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{l\ge 0}  \frac{(1/3)_l}{l!}\frac{(2l)!}{2^{2l}(l!)^2}
=
\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{l\ge 0}  \frac{(1/3)_l}{l!}\frac{\Gamma(2l+1)}{2^{2l}\Gamma^2(l+1)}
$$
$$
=
\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{l\ge 0}  \frac{(1/3)_l}{l!}\frac{\Gamma(l+1/2)\Gamma(l+1)2^{2l+1/2}}{2^{2l}\Gamma^2(l+1)}
$$
$$
=
\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{l\ge 0}  \frac{(1/3)_l}{l!}\frac{\Gamma(l+1/2)}{\Gamma(l+1)}
$$
$$
=
\frac{\surd \pi}{2}\Gamma(1/2)\sum_{l\ge 0}  \frac{(1/3)_l}{l!}\frac{(1/2)_l}{(1)_l}
$$
$$
=
\frac{\pi}{2}{}_2F_1(1/3,1/2 ; 1; 1)
=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma(5/6)\Gamma(2/3)}.
$$
This is the same result as with the original formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot...